# Winsock не желает биндить сокет

Tags: сокет, c++

Подскажите, что делаю не так. При запуске получаю ответ "bind() failed."

```
#include <iostream>

#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void server(unsigned short port)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    SOCKET MainSock;
    SOCKET ClientSock;

    sockaddr_in MyAddr;
    sockaddr_in RemoteAddr;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup() failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (MainSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "socket() failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    MyAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    MyAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    MyAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    //memset(&(MyAddr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    if (bind(MainSock, (sockaddr *)&MyAddr, sizeof(MyAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "bind() failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(MainSock, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "listen() failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t addrlen = sizeof(RemoteAddr);
    if (ClientSock = accept(MainSock, (sockaddr *)&RemoteAddr, (int *)&addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "accept() failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t size_byte;
    char buffer[256];
    if (size_byte = recv(ClientSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) <= 0)
    {
        if(size_byte == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error recv()." << std::endl; 
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "recv() failed." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (send(ClientSock, buffer, size_byte, 0) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "send() failed." << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket(ClientSock);

    closesocket(MainSock);

    WSACleanup();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    server(23758);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приоритет операции "==" (равенство) выше приоритета операции "=" (присваивание), поэтому в строке

```
if (MainSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

переменная MainSock получает значение 0

Comment: Спс дружище. да уж такой феил.

Comment: Точно, я тоже минут 20 сравнивал со своим работающим кодом и в упор не видел ошибочку. 

А всего и надо-то было не лениться и вставить после bind():

    fprintf (stderr,"WSAGetLastError(): %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

а потом найти, что 10038 это

    WSAENOTSOCK (10038) Socket operation on non-socket.

Comment: WSAGetLastError. Так вот как они называют наш perror...

Comment: К сожалению это не совсем perror(). WSAGetLastError() возвращает код ошибки (число). Для извлечения строки потом по идее надо вызывать  FormatMessage() с кучей аргументов, в которых я не удосужился разобраться.